# When should we avoid overfitting?

Tags: modeling, overfitting

In the case of model fitting, if we are sure both training and test data have no noise, still must avoid overfitting? (training data may be insufficient)

Comment: What do you mean the training and test data have no noise? If there is no noise, your data are produced by a deterministic process and you wouldn't need statistical models.

Comment: for example in the case of curve fitting (simple regression), I have just a series of training noise-free data and their labels and want to guess a model for prediction (the formula and parameters are unknown).How to handle extra oscillations (training data are exact but may be insufficient or non-covering)?

Comment: Does overfitting phenomenon occurs just for non-determinestic (noisy) data?

Comment: for example when using polynomial curve fitting on deterministic data, we don't know the number of parameters and polynomial degree and the number of training data is small.does techniques for avoid overfitting help for having a finer model?

Comment: @mrmr So you are saying that there is no noise in the data - no randomness, but you still do not know the process that generates the data? So you are asking how to know if the model has overfit? For ex. if a model with a second degree polynomial fits just as well as a third degree polynomial then the third degree is overfit?

Comment: yes, for example 9th degree fits best on data, but because of insufficiency of training data, applying model on test data gets poor results. Can overfitting avoidance techniques help modify oscillations of the model?

Comment: All the rest being equal, how on earth did you get your hands on a dataset where both dependent and independent variables are deterministic and measured with perfect precision, and where can I get some? Otherwise, the overfitted model will start to come apart when faced with real data just by simple fact of noisy measurements.

Comment: Suppose conditions are ideal!

Comment: If "training data are exact" then how can there be "extra oscillations"?

Comment: or may have missed peaks (oscillations).

Comment: This situation in not uncommon. for example you are distilling another neural network or you trying to reverse engineer some rule based system. many scenarios .

Comment: that being said , i think overfitting can still happen. For example you have 2 data points and if you try fitting a degree 10 polynomial , there are many hypothesis that can fit with 0 error , not all of them will generalize. overfitting is a property of hypothesis space and number of data points one is trying to fit. noise or noise free does not make much of a difference .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF** you have absolutely no noise and **IF** your process is generated from a nice function which you can calculate with curve fitting - such as polynomial (doubt), then overfitting does not occur. However, you may still want to avoid it anyway, since it is unnecessary.

To illustrate here is an example in R. We generate 10 points from a third degree polynomial function with no noise. Then we fit linear models with degree 1 to 6 and plot the fits.

```
x=runif(10,-5,5)
y=x^3+2*x^2-x+4

par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for (i in 1:6) {
  plot(y~x)
  lines(predict(lm(y~poly(x,i)),test)~test$x,col=i)
}
```

[image]

As you can see after the third degree polynomial (image [1,3]) there is no change. Using an ANOVA

```
anova(lm(y~x),
      lm(y~poly(x,2)),
      lm(y~poly(x,3)),
      lm(y~poly(x,4)),
      lm(y~poly(x,5)))

Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ x
Model 2: y ~ poly(x, 2)
Model 3: y ~ poly(x, 3)
Model 4: y ~ poly(x, 4)
Model 5: y ~ poly(x, 5)
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq          F Pr(>F)    
1      8 7538.8                                   
2      7 2893.3  1    4645.5 1.6511e+31 <2e-16 ***
3      6    0.0  1    2893.3 1.0283e+31 <2e-16 ***
4      5    0.0  1       0.0 1.6439e+00 0.2691    
5      4    0.0  1       0.0 2.0833e+00 0.2224    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

will select the model with degree 3.

**Update**: in case you do not know the underlying model and have few data points then you run the risk of overfitting. Consider another scenario where the data come from a sine function with holes in the data and no noise, and we try to estimate the model using polynomials.

```
x=c(runif(10,-20,-10),runif(10,10,20))
y=sin(x)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but what about the case we dont know the model and training data is small (dataset is exact but not fully-covering). https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNvBK.png

Comment: @mrmr In that case things get more complicated, especially if you have large gaps in the data, and you may as well treat it as any other statistical problem, which means you want to be conservative and avoid overfitting.